# notsupportedexception error thrown when trying to pull data for a Dropdown list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't understand why this is happening but the website works fine until you try to access the create a booking View and it throws a "NotSupportedException was unhandle by user code" Error.

This is the part where the error gets thrown from the ViewBag onwards:

```
    // GET: /Home/BookaFlight
    public ActionResult BookaFlight()
    {
        ViewBag.FlightsList = (from L in ss.FlightsTbls select new { ID = L.Flight_Id, text = L.Departing_Airport + "to" + L.Arriving_Airport + " " + L.Daily_Flight_Number }).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

This relevant code for the model storing the data for the dropdown and so on:

```
namespace Assignment_2_Flight_Booking_Website.Models
{
public class BookingValidation
{

    public int Flight_ID { get; set; }

}
}
```

And finally the view which won't open (Only dropdown part shown):

```
<h2>BookaFlight</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Flight_ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.FlightsList, "ID", "text"))</td>
```

Please help I haven't a clue whats going wrong and I also want to mention it's all being stored on an SQL database. I can't see whats causing the error at first I though it might be to do with The Flight_ID being stored as an int and not a String but converting it to a string does nothing and just won't work. it worked before I added the dropdown.

Error details:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Which line in your code throws that error?

Comment: ViewBag.FlightsList = (from L in ss.FlightsTbls select new { ID = L.Flight_Id, text = L.Departing_Airport + "to" + L.Arriving_Airport + " " + L.Daily_Flight_Number }).ToList(); 
that line in the controller under the View for BookaFlight.

Comment: I suggest you remove most of the code from your question and show only the relevant bits (are all those using statements relevant? or the code to create a mail message?)

Comment: Sorry new to posting on here and just copied it over thinking may be relevant sorted it now tho

Comment: Is the error thrown in the controller - i.e before you hit `return View();` or in the view itself?

Comment: Yh it's thrown before you hit the `return View();` and if commented out it throws the same error in `[HttpPost]` in the same controllerwheres it's repeated for the validation model.

Comment: Can you show the full error details

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Is `Daily_Flight_Number` an int?

Comment: Yes it is and think I know where you're going

Comment: Even so, it should work. That error usually occurs when you use something like `.Equals()` or similar in a query.

Comment: I removed the `Daily_Flight_Number` part from `Text = .....` and now it all works perfectly

Comment: You can always do `(from L in ss.FlightsTbls select L).ToList().Select(f => new { ID = L.Flight_Id, text = string.Format("{0} to {1} {2}", f.Departing_Airport, f.Arriving_Airport,f.Daily_Flight_Number });` so the query is materialized to a collection of objects first.